# React Native word search puzzle dragging behaviour

Tags: react-native, wordsearch

In this section I have posted a screenshot of word puzzle game from some other resources which is made on web.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPTGt.png)
Now, I'm trying to implement this type of game for mobile using React Native, but where I'm stucking is that I can't understood the problem how this selecting the word works?
like i selected the word from starting point to ending point while selecting the word.

can anyone help me out to how to resolve this type of problem.

I'm trying to implement the dragging behaviour in react-native. how the logic works?